# require_once raise HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php

I'm working in a team on a e-shop website.

Recently, we've passed on Debian Jessie and from php5.4 to 5.6

Since then, we have multiple bug with require and require_once

Here's a file that raise an ERROR 500

```
<?php
require('/data/vhosts/mycompany.com/public_html/mp/../includes/functions/marketplace_tools.php');
//print_r(get_included_files());

require_once('/data/vhosts/mycompany.com/public_html/mp/../includes/functions/marketplace_tools.php');
echo 'pouet';
?>
```

The error.log say this :

`PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare match_marketplace_products() in Cannot redeclare match_marketplace_products() on line 1`

- The filepath is good.
- Marketplace_tools.php don't have require/include in
- Marketplace_tools.php is just a bunch of function we use
- If I run this file in command line, it works well
- If I uncomment the print_r, it does not raise ERROR 500
- This bug randomly appear and disapear

Comment: why .... in between the path? provide full path there?

Comment: @Anant I'm pretty sure it's for our sake so that the line doesn't get TOO long.

Comment: Is that the only error? It looks like you've edited the error but that makes it harder to answer. There doesn't seem to be enough information here (for me at least).

Comment: @Henders : There is the complete error :

 `[06-Oct-2016 17:18:01 Europe/Paris] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare match_marketplace_products() in Cannot redeclare match_marketplace_products() on line 18`

Answer (score 0):

`Cannot redeclare match_marketplace_products()`

This error message tells you that there is a function name (`match_marketplace_products`) in the file you're including that already exists in the current PHP program.

You're using `require_once()`, but check that you haven't pulled in the same file elsewhere using `require()` (or `include()`).

Also check that the function name `match_marketplace_products` is only defined in this one file -- if it's defined in another file that is also included, then this will cause this error.

Comment: As said : marketplace_tools don't have any require/include inside.
The only place where there is require is in this file.
And yes, mathc_marketplace_products is only defined once in marketplace_products_tools.